# How do I edit vue data passed as a property?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a Vuex data store with an array of `contacts`.  I display that array in `ContactList.vue`, where I have an "Edit" button that navigates to CreateEditContact.vue (I am passing in the `contact` as a prop named `contactProp`).  All of this works, but as we all know, you can't edit a prop directly.  I tried checking to see if the prop is populated when the template is `created`, and copying it to `contact` in `data` but it isn't working.  What's the *right* way to do this?

**ContactList.vue**

```html
<template>
    <!-- ...redacted for brevity -->

    <!-- I'm reusing the same .vue for creating new and editing contacts -->

    <!-- edit contact button -->
    <v-btn text
           :to="{name: 'createEditContact',
                  params: {
                    action: 'edit',
                    id: contact.id,
                    contactProp: contact
                  }}">Edit</v-btn>

    <!-- new contact button --> 
    <v-btn
        :to="{ name: 'createEditContact', params: { action: 'create' } }"
        outlined
        rounded>New</v-btn>

</template>
```

**CreateEditContact.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Create or Edit a Contact</h3>
    <v-form @submit.prevent="saveContact">
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col>
            <v-text-field label="Name" v-model="contact.name" />
          </v-col>
          <v-col>
            <v-text-field label="Phone Number" v-model="contact.phone" />
          </v-col>
          <v-col>
            <v-text-field label="Extension" v-model="contact.extension" />
          </v-col>
          <v-col>
            <v-btn type="submit">Save</v-btn>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from "axios";

    const options = {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    };

    export default {
        name: "CreateEditContact",
        props: {
            action: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
                validator: value => ["create", "edit"].indexOf(value) !== -1
            },
            id: {
                required: false
            },
            // contactProp gets set correctly when editing...
            contactProp: {}
        },
        data() {
            return {
                // the empty contact (when creating a new contact)
                contact: {
                    id: 0,
                    name: "",
                    phone: "",
                    extension: "",
                    fullString: "",
                    telephoneUrl: ""
                }
            };
        },
        methods: {
            saveContact() {
                // redacted for brevity
            },
            created() {
                // when contactProp is populated, I need to use that... 
                // but contact is always empty when I try to edit one.
                // this next line isn't doing what I think it should.
                if (this.contactProp) this.contact = this.contactProp;
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: The `created` lifecycle hook belongs outside of `methods`.

Comment: Moving the hook seems to [resolve the issue](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-vue?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FCreateEditContact.vue&theme=dark).